# Elasticsearch: Renew expired document (_ttl expired)

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a Index with a default ttl time from x days. I have documents, which will updated in the persistent database (postgres, mysql or so). If a document updated, it must be renew in Elasticsearch. But after a document expired only the Exception throws:

```
{
   "error": "RemoteTransportException[[es][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]][indices:data/write/index]]; nested: MapperParsingException[failed to parse [_ttl]]; nested: AlreadyExpiredException[already expired [index]/[type]/[1] due to expire at [146901939600] and was processed at [1430247194395]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

Any possibilities to renew a document if its already expired?

Comment: did you finally find any solution to this?