# Renew _ttl on an already expired document

Tags: elasticsearch, java-client

I'm trying to update a ttl of a document which is already expired but has not been deleted yet by the elasticsearch's bulk operation which is configured with

I get the followin error:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [_ttl]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:411)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.internal.TTLFieldMapper.postParse(TTLFieldMapper.java:174)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:552)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:493)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.IndexShard.prepareIndex(IndexShard.java:493)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:192)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:574)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase.routeRequestOrPerformLocally(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:444)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$PrimaryPhase.doRun(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:370)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:36)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.doExecute(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.innerExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:136)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.doExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:114)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.doExecute(TransportIndexAction.java:63)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:217)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.update.TransportUpdateAction.shardOperation(TransportUpdateAction.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.action.support.single.instance.TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction$AsyncSingleAction$1.run(TransportInstanceSingleOperationAction.java:187)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.AlreadyExpiredException: already expired [my_index]/[my_type]/[AU62OunMJpm4BthfuL_1] due to expire at [1437576451116] and was processed at [1437576461112]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.internal.TTLFieldMapper.innerParseCreateField(TTLFieldMapper.java:212)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.NumberFieldMapper.parseCreateField(NumberFieldMapper.java:239)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:401)
        ... 20 more
```

I have noticed about bug: [#8715](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/8715). Is it by somehow related and will it fix the problem? I perform a scripted update.

To what version of elasticsearch will it be incluced? 1.7.1?

there is also the same problem asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29927757/elasticsearch-renew-expired-document-ttl-expired) some time ago

Comment: The issue is tagged with 2.0.

Comment: Thank you Louis, for your reply! do you know if it will it fix this problem  that I mention?